# Package alterqcm greek error

Tags: errors, alterqcm

Though the `alterqcm` package works fine by using the `[english]` option when loading the package and despite the fact that there is a `greek` option too, the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[greek]{alterqcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[lq=8cm]
 \AQquestion{Ερώτηση 1}{%
 {Απάντηση 1},
 {Απάντηση 2},
 {Απάντηση 3}}
\end{alterqcm}

\end{document}
```

produces these errors

> Undefined control sequence. {Απάντηση 3}}
>
> Missing \endcsname inserted. {Απάντηση 3}}
>
> Extra \endcsname. {Απάντηση 3}}

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble?

Comment: Yes. But no luck. Instead of showing the answers in a seperate box, all the text is in the question box. And the error remains.